# Вложенные циклы FOR

Tags: c#, циклы

Здравствуйте.
Имеется вложенный цикл, который должен заполнить два двумерных массива (не имеет разницы что их два), в котором содержаться строки.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < list2.Count; j++) 
            {
                XmlElement per1 = (XmlElement)xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("RAZDEL")[i];
                XmlElement per2 = (XmlElement)xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("THEME")[j];
                iConT[i, j] = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) + per2.GetAttribute("icon_path").ToString();
                iRazdelT[i,j] = per2.GetAttribute("name").ToString();
            }
         }
```

тоесть он должен иметь допустим 4 строки (i) и разное количество заполненных столбцов (j), они заполняются из XML файла. после этого я обращаюсь к определенной строке массива и хочу получить содержимое ее столбцов, но мне все время выдаются столбцы только первой строки, независимо от того к какой строке я обратился. Что я делаю не так?

сам XML

```
<TOXT>
<RAZDEL id="1" name="ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИЕ ОСНОВЫ И АППАРАТУРНОЕ ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ ПРОЦЕССОВ ХИМИЧЕСКОГО ПРЕВРАЩЕНИЯ ВЕЩЕСТВ." icon_path="/img/logo.png">
    <THEME number="1" name="Понятие и структура химико-технологического процесса." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="2" name="Показатели химико-технологического процесса." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="3" name="Классификация химических реакций." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="4" name="Термодинамические характеристики химических реакций." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="5" name="Расчет теплового баланса реакций." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
</RAZDEL>

<RAZDEL id="2" name="ХИМИКО-ТЕХНОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ СИСТЕМЫ." icon_path="/img/000.jpg">
    <THEME number="1" name="Основные типы химико-технологических систем и их особенности." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="2" name="Формирование технологических схем на основе системного анализа." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
</RAZDEL>

<RAZDEL id="3" name="ПРОИЗВОДСТВО ОСНОВНЫХ ПРОДУКТОВ НЕОРГАНИЧЕСКОГО СИНТЕЗА." icon_path="/img/222.jpg">
    <THEME number="1" name="Производство серной кислоты." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="2" name="Производство аммиака." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="3" name="Производство азотной кислоты." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
</RAZDEL>

<RAZDEL id="4" name="ХИМИЧЕСКИЕ ПРОИЗВОДСТВА И ОКРУЖАЮЩАЯ СРЕДА." icon_path="/img/333.jpg">
    <THEME number="1" name="Классификация промышленных загрязнений." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="2" name="Источники загрязнения." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="3" name="Защита атмосферы от вредных воздействий." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="4" name="Очистка сточных вод." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="5" name="Переработка твердых отходов." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="6" name="Принципы создания малоотходных технологических процессов." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="7" name="Экологические аспекты при проектировании новых, расширении и реконструкции действующих производств." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
</RAZDEL>
</TOXT>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понятны вырванные из контекста `list1.Count` и `list2.Count` а также не задействованная `per1`.

Надеюсь, вы помните, что

```
per2 = (XmlElement)xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("THEME")
```

будет содержать элементы со всего документа, а не текущего узла (`RAZDEL`)?

Как вариант, можно брать все узлы `RAZDEL` и перебирать их детей.
Я бы в данном случае поступил немного по другому: перебрал бы список узлов `THEME`, ориентируясь на родителя узла. Что-то вроде этого:

```
var theme = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("THEME");
foreach (XmlElement th in theme)
{
    string the = "";
    var attr = th.GetAttribute("icon_path");
    var numb = th.GetAttribute("number");
    if (th.Attributes.Count > 0)
    {
        the = th.ParentNode.Attributes[0].Value;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(th.ParentNode.Name + " " + the + ", " + th.Name + " " + numb + ": " + attr + "  " + th.GetAttribute("name"));
}
```

Таким образом, беря необходимые значения, Вы можете создать нужный массив.
Также сюда нужно добавить проверки на существование узлов/аттрибутов, чтобы не получить null вместо какого-нибудь значения.

Немного изменённый xml, чтобы было более наглядно видно, что за строка обрабатывается

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TOXT>
  <RAZDEL id="r1" name="ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИЕ ОСНОВЫ И АППАРАТУРНОЕ ОФОРМЛЕНИЕ ПРОЦЕССОВ ХИМИЧЕСКОГО ПРЕВРАЩЕНИЯ ВЕЩЕСТВ." icon_path="/img/logo.png">
    <THEME number="r1t1" name="Понятие и структура химико-технологического процесса." icon_path="/img/11.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r1t2" name="Показатели химико-технологического процесса." icon_path="/img/12.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r1t3" name="Классификация химических реакций." icon_path="/img/13.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r1t4" name="Термодинамические характеристики химических реакций." icon_path="/img/14.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r1t5" name="Расчет теплового баланса реакций." icon_path="/img/15.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
  </RAZDEL>

  <RAZDEL id="r2" name="ХИМИКО-ТЕХНОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ СИСТЕМЫ." icon_path="/img/000.jpg">
    <THEME number="r2t1" name="Основные типы химико-технологических систем и их особенности." icon_path="/img/21.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r2t2" name="Формирование технологических схем на основе системного анализа." icon_path="/img/22.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
  </RAZDEL>

  <RAZDEL id="r3" name="ПРОИЗВОДСТВО ОСНОВНЫХ ПРОДУКТОВ НЕОРГАНИЧЕСКОГО СИНТЕЗА." icon_path="/img/222.jpg">
    <THEME number="r3t1" name="Производство серной кислоты." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r3t2" name="Производство аммиака." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r3t3" name="Производство азотной кислоты." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
  </RAZDEL>

  <RAZDEL id="r4" name="ХИМИЧЕСКИЕ ПРОИЗВОДСТВА И ОКРУЖАЮЩАЯ СРЕДА." icon_path="/img/333.jpg">
    <THEME number="r4t1" name="Классификация промышленных загрязнений." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t2" name="Источники загрязнения." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t3" name="Защита атмосферы от вредных воздействий." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t4" name="Очистка сточных вод." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t5" name="Переработка твердых отходов." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t6" name="Принципы создания малоотходных технологических процессов." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
    <THEME number="r4t7" name="Экологические аспекты при проектировании новых, расширении и реконструкции действующих производств." icon_path="/img/333.jpg" text_path="img/temi.rtf"/>
  </RAZDEL>
</TOXT>
```

результат:

```
RAZDEL r1, THEME r1t1: /img/11.jpg  Понятие и структура химико-технологического процесса.
RAZDEL r1, THEME r1t2: /img/12.jpg  Показатели химико-технологического процесса.
RAZDEL r1, THEME r1t3: /img/13.jpg  Классификация химических реакций.
RAZDEL r1, THEME r1t4: /img/14.jpg  Термодинамические характеристики химических реакций.
RAZDEL r1, THEME r1t5: /img/15.jpg  Расчет теплового баланса реакций.
RAZDEL r2, THEME r2t1: /img/21.jpg  Основные типы химико-технологических систем и их особенности.
RAZDEL r2, THEME r2t2: /img/22.jpg  Формирование технологических схем на основе системного анализа.
RAZDEL r3, THEME r3t1: /img/333.jpg  Производство серной кислоты.
RAZDEL r3, THEME r3t2: /img/333.jpg  Производство аммиака.
RAZDEL r3, THEME r3t3: /img/333.jpg  Производство азотной кислоты.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t1: /img/333.jpg  Классификация промышленных загрязнений.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t2: /img/333.jpg  Источники загрязнения.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t3: /img/333.jpg  Защита атмосферы от вредных воздействий.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t4: /img/333.jpg  Очистка сточных вод.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t5: /img/333.jpg  Переработка твердых отходов.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t6: /img/333.jpg  Принципы создания малоотходных технологических процессов.
RAZDEL r4, THEME r4t7: /img/333.jpg  Экологические аспекты при проектировании новых, расширении и реконструкции действующих производств.
```